# What Have I duplicated? I get the error - An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

Im having trouble getting this to execute in visual studio, what have I duplicated? Visual studio is giving me this error

"An error occurred while the query design method was being saved. An item with the same key has already been added."

```
 SELECT 
    oe_hdr.po_no,
    p21_view_invoice_hdr.invoice_no,
    p21_view_invoice_hdr.invoice_date,
    inv_mast.item_id,   
     inv_mast.item_desc,   
     oe_hdr.customer_id,   
     customer.customer_name,   
     oe_hdr.company_id,   
     company.company_name,   
     oe_hdr.order_no,   
     oe_hdr.order_date,   
     oe_line.required_date,   
     oe_line.unit_quantity,   
    oe_line.qty_allocated / oe_line.unit_size,   
    oe_line.qty_on_pick_tickets / oe_line.unit_size,   
     oe_line.qty_invoiced / oe_line.unit_size as 'invoiced',   
     oe_line.unit_of_measure,   
     oe_line.unit_size,   
     oe_line.disposition,   
     oe_line.unit_price,   
     oe_line.extended_price,   
     oe_line.source_loc_id,   
     location_source.location_name,   
     oe_line.ship_loc_id,   
     location_ship.location_name,   
     oe_line.supplier_id,   
     supplier.supplier_name,   
     oe_hdr.approved,   
     oe_line.complete,   
     oe_hdr.address_id,   
     oe_hdr.ship2_name,   
     oe_line.qty_canceled,   
     oe_line.pricing_unit,   
     oe_line.pricing_unit_size,   
     oe_line.qty_staged / oe_line.unit_size,   
     inv_mast.date_created,   
     inv_mast.date_last_modified,   
     inv_mast.last_maintained_by,
        oe_line.qty_canceled / unit_size c_qty_canceled,
        0 c_column_selected,
     CASE
        WHEN oe_hdr.order_type = 1877 THEN
            'Y'
        ELSE
            'N'
     END c_mfr_rep_orders,
        oe_hdr_mfr.vendor_id,   
    oe_hdr_mfr.external_po_no,
        oe_line_dealer_commission.dealer_commission_ext_amt,
    CASE WHEN oe_line.extended_price <> 0 THEN
        ((oe_line_dealer_commission.dealer_commission_ext_amt/oe_line.extended_price)*100)  
    ELSE
        0
    END
        ,oe_hdr.projected_order
        ,oe_hdr.order_type
        ,oe_hdr.rma_flag
FROM oe_hdr
join p21_view_invoice_hdr on oe_hdr.order_no = p21_view_invoice_hdr.order_no
     INNER JOIN oe_line  ON ( oe_hdr.order_no = oe_line.order_no )
     INNER JOIN inv_mast ON ( oe_line.inv_mast_uid = inv_mast.inv_mast_uid ) AND (inv_mast.product_type <> 'B')
     INNER JOIN customer ON ( oe_hdr.customer_id = customer.customer_id ) AND
                            ( oe_hdr.company_id = customer.company_id )
     INNER JOIN company  ON ( oe_hdr.company_id = company.company_id )
     INNER JOIN location location_source ON ( oe_line.source_loc_id = location_source.location_id )
     INNER JOIN location location_ship ON ( oe_line.ship_loc_id = location_ship.location_id )
     INNER JOIN supplier ON ( oe_line.supplier_id = supplier.supplier_id )
        LEFT JOIN oe_hdr_mfr ON (oe_hdr.oe_hdr_uid = oe_hdr_mfr.oe_hdr_uid)
        LEFT JOIN oe_line_dealer_commission ON (oe_line_dealer_commission.oe_line_uid = oe_line.oe_line_uid)
where ( oe_line.delete_flag = 'N' )

and (oe_hdr.company_id = '100')
and p21_view_invoice_hdr.invoice_date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
```

Answer (score 0):

my guess is give the proper column name for the following columns

```
oe_line.qty_allocated / oe_line.unit_size,   
oe_line.qty_on_pick_tickets / oe_line.unit_size,  
CASE WHEN oe_line.extended_price <> 0 THEN ((oe_line_dealer_commission.dealer_commission_ext_amt/oe_line.extended_price)*100)   ELSE 0 END
```